# Update values in struct arrays in BigQuery

Tags: sql, arrays, data-structures, google-bigquery

I am looking for an easy way to update values inside array of structs using SQL. Let's say we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table
(
    date DATE,
    weights ARRAY<STRUCT<animal STRING, value FLOAT64>>
)
;

insert into schema.table
select cast('2020-01-01' as date), [('dog', 10.2), ('bird', 0.7), ('dragon', 3.2)]
union all
select cast('2020-01-02' as date), [('dog', 10.3), ('bird', 0.7)]
union all
select cast('2020-01-03' as date), [('dragon', 3.3)]
```

So the table looks like:

[image]

I would somehow like to update this table and change all `dragon` names to a `cat`.

Comment: Do not worry, I always accept if it works. I am only "waiting" because I can not test it until Monday. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE `project.dataset.table` t
SET weights =  
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT IF(animal = 'dragon', 'cat', animal) animal, value
    FROM t.weights 
  ) 
WHERE TRUE
```

Comment: Do you know how I would do this for nested arrays? For example, if I have a schema like OP's except each record in `weights` had a column which itself was a repeated record column called `owners` (strings)? And my goal was to do some transformation on each of the owner? Do you think this kind of query warrants its own Stack Overflow question?

Comment: @MattWelke - please post your question with all relevant details, sample data and expected result - and I/we will be happy to help :o)

Comment: You're awesome! I'm actually stuck on the step where I put together that minimal example in order to ask the question. I ended up creating a question to learn what the problem is with the code I wrote to try to create the question. >.> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70428472/how-do-i-use-bigquery-dml-to-insert-a-row-with-an-array-within-a-struct-within-a

Comment: np. will check shortly as time allow :o)

Comment: Thanks for answering that! Now, I was able to complete the question I originally wanted to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429214/how-do-i-use-bigquery-dml-to-transform-some-fields-of-a-struct-nested-within-an