# How can I update a table that has struct inside a struct and both structs are inside an array? ARRAY<STRUCT<STRUCT>>

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following data structure:

```
id                    integer nullable
candidate             record  repeated
candidate.name        string  nullable
candidate.results     record  nullable
candidate.results.r1  integer nullable
candidate.results.r2  integer nullable
```

So, basically, its an array that has a struct and inside the struct it has another struct.
Something like this:

```
[struct("jp" as name, struct(null as r1, null as r2) as results)] candidate
```

How can I perform an update to this structure? I created some toy data with this and assigned random values between 0 and 1 using `cast(floor(2*rand()) as int64)` to the `candidate.results.r1` column. I would like to set `candidate.results.r2` to another random value `candidate.results.r1` `cast(floor(2*rand()) as int64)` where `candidate.results.r1` is equal to 1.

How can I achieve this?

---

EDIT:
Okay, I managed to "understand" (or I least I think I did) after looking to [this](http://https:/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61408952/update-values-in-struct-arrays-in-bigquery) other question and run this query successfuly:

```
update `mytable` t
set  candidate= array(
select as struct name,
(select as struct results.r1,
if(results.r1= 1,cast(floor(2*rand()) as int64),null) r2) results from t.candidate)
where true
```

What I want to know is why this works? Why there is no need to use `where` clause and just set it to `true`? And also, why that query works but this one fails:

```
update `mytable` t
set  candidate= array(
select as struct name,
(select as struct results.r1,
if(results.r1= 1,cast(floor(2*rand()) as int64),null) results.r2) results from t.candidate)
where true
```

Basically, adding `results` and making the `if statement` `if(results.r1= 1,cast(floor(2*rand()) as int64),null) results.r2` makes the query not valid. Why?

Comment: there are plenty of similar posts with answers - have you tried to do a little search first?

Comment: I did some searching and tried out some them, but I cannot get the query to be valid. Usually I found structs inside arrays, but I havent found yet a struct inside a struct inside an array. Maybe you could point me in the right direction? :)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant added an Edit part that has a solution and I "deduced" it based on other solution you gave. Would appreciate if you can explain me the "whys" of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why there is need to use where clause and just set it to true?

WHERE clause is a must part in UPDATE DML

*Each UPDATE statement must include the WHERE keyword, followed by a condition.

To update all rows in the table, use WHERE true.*

> Basically, adding results and making the if statement if(results.r1= 1,cast(floor(2*rand()) as int64),null) results.r2 makes the query not valid. Why?

`results.r2` in your second query is an alias and as such it is invalid - you should just use `r2` (as it is in your first query)

Comment: consider also voting up the answer :o)