# How do you swap two attributes in array column on Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with two columns: group_id, students (Array of student). Each student have a two attribute: name and last_name. How do you swap name with last_name for each student?

```
Students table:
group_id | students.name | students.last_name
---------------------------------------------
1        | Perez         | Juan
---------------------------------------------
2        | Caicedo       | Pedro
```

I need to swapping students.name to students.last_name, any idea?

Comment: Hi OP, can you please provide sample data and sample output for better replication of your use case?

Comment: Hi @ScottB thanks for you answer, but your approach is very hard and i needed a approach more soft and dynamic. Check out my answer and thank again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, thanks to Mikhail Berlyant who answered this question ([Update values in struct arrays in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61408952/update-values-in-struct-arrays-in-bigquery)), i was able to exchange attributes on update clause.

```
UPDATE `Students` s
SET students =  
   ARRAY(
       SELECT 
         AS STRUCT 
           last_name, name
       FROM s.students
   ) 
WHERE TRUE;
```

Too, i was able to exchange attributes on update clause with if condition for example.

```
UPDATE `Students` s
SET students =  
   ARRAY(
       SELECT 
         AS STRUCT 
           IF(CONTAINS_SUBSTR(name, 'Pedro'), name, last_name), IF(CONTAINS_SUBSTR(last_name, 'Caicedo'), last_name, name)
       FROM s.students
   ) 
WHERE TRUE;
```

It's very important the position in the STRUCT, in my case name is first and last_name is second,
for achieve the exchange just by changing its position the objective is achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You may try and consider the below approach.

```
with a as (
select [struct("Perez" as name,"Juan" as last_name),
        struct("Caicedo" as name,"Pedro" as last_name)]as students
)
select stdnts.name last_name, stdnts.last_name name
from a,unnest(students) as stdnts
```

We swapped the nested column name instead of the attribute values.

From here, based on the query results, you may create another schema with the update nested column names for `name` and `last_name`.

Or if your schema is too big and recreating it in BigQuery it not an option, you may overwrite your table by dropping the **students** array column table and then recreating it with the updated nested column names and still retain the data based on the above query.

The approach is derived from this [Changing Column Name Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#change_a_columns_name) but instead, we will be changing the Nested Column names.

Comment: Hi @ScottB thanks for you answer, but your approach is very hard and i needed a approach more soft and dynamic. Check out my answer and thank again :)